# Data exchange between daemon and launch agent

Tags: macos, ipc, daemon, agent

Mac OS X Snow Leopard and Lion. I have a daemon (which runs from root) and launch agent which runs from current user. How can daemon request data (or send command) to launch agent?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to achieve simple IPC between the daemon and agent, refer to my answer here : [OS X - Communication between launch daemon and launch agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11868069/os-x-communication-between-launch-daemon-and-launch-agent).

Make sure to set up this socket-based communication on separate threads, so as not to interrupt the flow of your program.